# Rate limit user input without using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, security, web

What are the possibilities for rate limiting user input without using JavaScript? The lesser round trips made to the server for this, the better.

Comment: Why 'without using JS'?  BTW - Java is certainly not the answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Requirement from the client.

Comment: Without using javascript and with little round trips. I think you would be limited to checking after the user clicks a submit button.

Comment: *"Requirement from the client."*  .. **Why** does the **client** require that?  Don't make me play 20 questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Accessibility requirements and security concerns are two reasons (in our case it is the former) which are no longer valid, but still insisted upon by clients.

Comment: @AndrewThompson "Don't make me play 20 questions." - What was that supposed to be? : - )

Comment: It was a comment to the effect that *"Requirement from the client."* is a *specification,* not an *explanation* of 'why'.

Answer (score 1):

Without JS, they only way to do this is to validate the input on the server and send back the page with error messages for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxlength` but need validate in backend too.